# Just looking to disable the splash screen in Microsoft Outlook 2007?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007

How to disable the splash screen in Microsoft Outlook 2007 ?

Comment: Just curiosity ... why the hell someone would want to remove the harmless splashscreen?

Comment: Have you ever opened Outlook? The splash screen can take 5 or 10 seconds of the loading time. Clearly disabling will make Outlook load faster.

Comment: Disabling the splash screen (if it were possible) will not speed up Outlook startup! It is displayed while Outlook is starting up in the background so you don't wonder why nothing happens when you click the shortcut. If your Outlook startup is taking a long time, try to find out why it is taking so long. If you look around on the internets you will find that a number of people have been happier after disabling the Instant Messaging option.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is not possible to disable the splash screen inside the program. You may find the following application will stop the splash screen for Outlook 2007:

http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/SplashKiller/index.html

Alternatively:

1. Double click on the Outlook icon
2. Close your eyes
3. Count to 10 (slowly, no cheating!)
4. Open your eyes
5. Outlook will appear in front of you, you will not have to see the splash screen.

Comment: Lateral thinking!

Comment: SplashKiller did not work on an XP box

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SplashKiller](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/SplashKiller/index.html)

It's working for Office XP and 2003.

> SplashKiller lets you hide those splash screens that appear when an application is loading.
>
> It saves you from having to:
>
> 1. Find a 'no splash screen' option (if one exists) in the application.
> 2. Modify your registry to turn off a splash screen.
> 3. Hack the application itself to remove the splash screen.